# TypeScript: Overloaded functions/methods with object argument and IntelliSense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, overloading, intellisense, signature

I tried to overload a function `f` like this (just an example of course):

```
function f(params: {x: number, y: number}): number;
function f(params: {x: number, z: number}): number;
function f(params: {x: number, y: number} | {x: number, z: number}): number {
  if ('y' in params) return params.x + params.y;
  if ('z' in params) return params.x * params.z;
}
```

This already causes a problem because the compiler gives me `“Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)”`. This is strange, as one of the two `if` conditions in the implementation always must be fulfilled.

But I'm here for something different (which, however, is probably related): When I want to call `f` and therefore write something like `f({y: 4,`  and then press Ctrl+Shift+Space to activate IntelliSense (in VSCode 1.58.2), it makes two suggestions for missing properties (see picture): `x`, which is correct, but also `z`, which cannot fit anymore.

I would expect that as soon as I enter `y`, the type of `params` is narrowed to `{x: number, y: number}`, but this does not seem to happen. Why is that and can I do anything to change it?

[image: Example for IntelliSense not working correctly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your issues depend on the fact that union types in Typescript are **not exclusive**. You can find several discussions on this topic:

[XOR in union allows both](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10575#issuecomment-242919644)

[Proposal: Add an "exclusive or" (^) operator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094)

While this behaviour might seem confusing (it still is for me, to some extent) it explains:

1. why your two `if` conditions are not considered exhaustive by the Typescript compiler: in fact you still could have the case where `params` has *both* `x` and `z`
2. why Intellisense is showing `x`, `y`, and `z` as possible properties of `params`: in fact this is considered a valid assignment by TS:

`const a: { x: number, y: number } | { x: number, z: number } = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}`

Comment: Thanks! Indeed confusing; I would not have expected that, but now it makes perfect sense why my problems appear.